# Consolidating different worksheets into a main excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to VBA and I have just been learning the basics and the VBA language recently from Youtube and communities such as these. Therefore, any help will be really appreciated!

I am trying to consolidate excel worksheets from different excel workbooks into a main excel workbook. The excel workbooks are all found in the same file. However, they are named differently and I only have the partial names for the excel workbooks e.g. "ABG_RSPB_xxxxx-yyyy".

I will have a main workbook in the folder consolidating the data from all the different workbook and worksheets. Each workbook where the data is extracted from only has one worksheet and the template in each worksheet is the same. They have the same headers as well. All the workbooks are csv format. However the worksheets have partial names as well (the worksheet will have the same name as the workbook it is in).

Currently, I have a macro that provides a similar function however, it can't extract workbooks and worksheets with partial names.

Any help to amend the macro such that it can extract from partial workbooks and worksheets will be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Current code:

```
Sub consolidation ()

Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook 
Dim mainPath As String
mainPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Dim mainRowstart As Integer
mainRowstart = 2
Dim mainRC As Integer
mainRC = lastRow ("Consolidated Trades", "A") + 1

If mainRC < mainRowStart Then
        mainRC = mainRowStart
EndIf

Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim files As Object
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folderPaths = fso.getfolder (mainPath)
set filePaths = folderPath.files

Dim curFile As String
Dim curPath As String
Dim curRC As Integer
Dim curWSName As String
curWSName = ""

For Each filePath In filePaths
        curPath = filePath
        curFile = Split (curPath, "\")(UBound(Split(curPath, "\")))

                    If Left (curFile, 1) <> "~" Then
                            If curFile <> "ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.csv" Then 
                                    If Right (curFile, Len ("ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.xlsm")) =                                                                                 "ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.xlsm" Or _ Right (curFile, Len("ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.xls")) = "ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.xls" Then 

            Workbooks.Open Filename: = curPath
            Workbooks (curFile).Activate

            For Each ws In Worksheets 
            If ws.Name = "ABG_RSPB_xxxxx=yyy.csv" Then
                    curWSName = ws.Name
            End If

    Next Ws

            curRC = lastRow(CurWSName, "A")
            mainWB.Activate
            mainRC = lastrow("Consolidated Trades", "A") + 1

    If curRC >= 2 Then

            mainWB.Worksheets("Consolidated Trades").Range("A" & mainRC & ":U: & mainRC + curRC - 2).Value = _ Workbooks(curFile).Worksheets(curWSName).Range("A2:U" & curRC).Value

            mainWB.Worksheets("Consolidated Trades").Range("V" & mainRC).Value = curFile & "with" & curRC -1 & "Rows of Data"

            EndIf

            Workbooks(curFile).Close

            EndIf
        EndIf
      EndIf
    NextfilePath

MsgBox "Process Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru Thank you so much for helping out with my previous question, I have included a code I have in another workbook and I hope these helps you to understand a bit more about what I am trying to do. As for your previous questions,
1. The main consolidated workbook will have the headers, so I will only need to import and consolidate the data
2. All workbooks have a single sheet so I guess we can just identify them based on the worksheet number
3. I would like to consolidate them in the file with the VBA code and the files are all csv format apart from the main wb. 
Thank u so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997432/consolidating-different-files-into-one-main-worksheet

Comment: Maybe you should take a look  to „Get and Transform“  Functions in Excel. With PowerQuery ist is easy to consolidate data from a lot of files in the same folder.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "partial names". Would you please explain the main problem in a more clear way?

Comment: A csv file is not a "workbook" - it happens to be a type of file which Excel can open and parse, but it has no "worksheets" and so also no worksheet names - the tab name displayed in Excel is just the file name.  In any case `Worksheets(1)` will always work fine with a CSV file (since there are never more than 1 worksheet when a CSV is opened in Excel)

Comment: Hi @SaeedSayyadipour what I mean by "Partial names" is that all the files in the folder have the same name with variants at the end of the name. For example file 1 would be called ABG_RSPB - 0001 while file 2 would be called ABG_RSPB - 0002 etc. Thanks

Comment: Hi dear @braX. Ok, got it. I'll post the answer in a while.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you have some csv files besides your main workbook and you want to iterate over all csv files and read all values in the first column of the first sheet of each file and then write them into the first column of the main workbook, right?
I've assumed that:

1. all csv files are desired and should be read (i.e., there is no csv file that you do not want to read it)
2. You have a subroutine called "lastrow" that finds the last row in a column of a sheet

Please see if the following code does the job correctly. If there is any problem, please leave a comment below, I'll see and edit my code as you want.

```
Sub consolidation()

    Dim mainRowstart As Integer
    mainRowstart = 2
    Dim mainRC As Integer
    mainRC = lastrow("Consolidated Trades", "A") + 1 'I've assumed that you have another sub called "lastrow"
    If mainRC < mainRowstart Then
            mainRC = mainRowstart
    End If

    '======================================================================================================
    '   1- Get all csv files in this workbook's path
    '======================================================================================================
    Dim allCsvFiles() As Variant
    allCsvFiles = GetFileList(ThisWorkbook.path, "csv")

    '======================================================================================================
    '   2- Loop over and read/write all data
    '======================================================================================================
    If IsArray(allCsvFiles) Then 'i.e., at least one file has found

        Dim file As Variant
        For Each file In allCsvFiles

            'Open file
            Workbooks.Open (file)

            'Activate
            Workbooks(file).Activate


            'How many rows do exist in the file?
            Dim curRC As Integer
            curRC = lastrow(Workbooks(file).Sheets(1).Name, "A") 'Hint: as the file is a "csv" file, it always contains only one sheet and there is no need to search and find a specific sheet

            If curRC > 2 Then

                mainRC = lastrow("Consolidated Trades", "A") + 1 'Is it required to run this function in every iteration???

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Trades").Range("V" & mainRC).Value = file & " with " & curRC - 1 & " rows of data"


                'Read and write data
                Dim row As Integer
                For row = 2 To curRC

                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Trades").Cells(mainRC, 1).Value = Workbooks(file).Sheets(1).Cells(row, 1).Value
                    mainRC = mainRC + 1

                Next row
            End If

            'Close file
            Workbooks(file).Close False

        Next

        MsgBox "Process Complete"

    End If   

End Sub
```

where `GetFileList` is:

```
Function GetFileList(path As String, FileSpec As String) As Variant

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(path & "\*." & FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

'   Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)

        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```